# Why ruby installed from RubyInstaller doesn't find dll's placed inside gem/lib folder?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

My system: windows 7 x64.

I've installed:

- ruby from RubyInstaller (1.8.7)
- gem install rake
- gem install libxml-ruby --platform=mswin32

Now, when I make:

```
require 'xml'
```

I get error about missing libxml2-2.dll (and libiconv-2.dll). I can find those two libraries in 'Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\libxml-ruby-1.1.4-x86-mswin32-60\lib\'. When I copy them into 'Ruby187\bin' folder everything works.

But...

If I install ruby from old OneClick Installer, libxml-ruby works without copying those dll's into ruby\bin folder. I've looked into PATH variable - it's not pointing into libxml-ruby lib folder, so IMHO ruby finds them in some other way.

And question. What can I do, so ruby from RubyInstaller act similarily to the one from OneClick Installer? I don't want to add \lib folder into PATH (OneClick Installer doesn't need that) and I don't want to copy dll's into Ruby\bin

Comment: Have you checked the `$:` variable?

Comment: @Martin Carpenter bingo :) Any idea why it wasn't added there? In both installations I have RubyGems 1.3.7

Comment: You need to check with libxml-ruby author to support mingw32 platform in his gems. It might not find the DLLs due incorrect RUBY_PLATFORM matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) installer, if seing no way around it.
(I have it working with many gems, in Win 7 64 bits, no issues to date...)